# Does browser use cache automaticly?

Tags: html, caching

Okay, so basicly I have this website that auto refreshes every couple of seconds, but there's like 30 or so images that appear on the page. Will the browser automaticly put them in the cache and re-use them the next time that it loads the page? Or is there away for me to do that manually? (or is there a way to store them on the user's computer and then load the images from his/her computer rather than my server?)

thanks

Comment: http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by default the images (and JavaScript and CSS) are cached on user's hard disk. Unless, you change the image's HTTP Headers. See this for more about HTTP caching (in browsers): [Caching Tutorial: for Web Authors and Webmasters](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/)